# Data wrangling widen and consolidate rows

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-manipulation, data-wrangling

I want to widen a number of rows and then consolidate the rows using R.

| Group ID | Person | Role | Payoff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| group_1 | person_1 | A | 10 |
| group_1 | person_2 | B | 20 |
| group_2 | person_3 | A | 14 |
| group_2 | person_4 | B | 14 |
| group_3 | person_5 | A | 34 |
| group_3 | person_6 | B | 48 |

When I use `pivot_wider(names_from = Role, values_from = c(Person, Payoff))` the data looks like this:

| Group ID | A | B | A Payoff | B Payoff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| group_1 | person_1 | NA | 10 | NA |
| group_1 | NA | person_2 | NA | 20 |
| group_2 | person_3 | NA | 14 | NA |
| group_2 | NA | person_4 | NA | 14 |
| group_3 | person_5 | NA | 34 | NA |
| group_3 | NA | person_6 | Na | 48 |

However, I want data to look the table below. Is there a different command I should be using or another way `pivot_wider` should be used?

| Group ID | A | B | A Payoff | B Payoff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| group_1 | person_1 | person_2 | 10 | 20 |
| group_2 | person_3 | person_4 | 14 | 14 |
| group_3 | person_5 | person_6 | 34 | 48 |

I also tried code similar to the following commands

```r
data %>%
  group_by('session_group_id') %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Role, values_from = c(Person, Payoff))
```

and

```r
data %>%
  group_by('session_group_id') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Role,
              values_from = c(Person, Payoff),
              values_fn = list)
```

Comment: As with @DaveArmstrong, your code `dat %>% pivot_wider(names_from = Role, values_from = c(Person, Payoff))` worked for me too. Dave's example has an underscore in what you have as the "Group ID" column, but I tried it with and without an underscore and it worked both ways.

Comment: Does the issue persist if you run your `pivot_wider()` code on the following df: `dat <- data.frame("Group ID" = rep(sprintf("group_%s",seq(1:3)), each = 2), Person = sprintf("person_%s",seq(1:6)), Role = rep(c("A", "B"), 3), Payoff = c(10,20,14,14,34,48), check.names = FALSE)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your code, I get the right answer (`tidyr` v 1.3.0, `dplyr` v 1.1.0):

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, 
           text="
Group_ID    Person  Role    Payoff
group_1 person_1    A   10
group_1 person_2    B   20
group_2 person_3    A   14
group_2 person_4    B   14
group_3 person_5    A   34
group_3 person_6    B   48
")
dat %>% pivot_wider(names_from = Role, values_from = c(Person, Payoff))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>   Group_ID Person_A Person_B Payoff_A Payoff_B
#>   <chr>    <chr>    <chr>       <int>    <int>
#> 1 group_1  person_1 person_2       10       20
#> 2 group_2  person_3 person_4       14       14
#> 3 group_3  person_5 person_6       34       48
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>